# floating menu css problem with IE8

Tags: css

This CSS works perfectly in Firefox but not in IE8.

```
.toc {
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:black 1px solid;
    color:white;
    max-height:50%;
    max-width:25%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 0;
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    top:40px;
}

.toc li { color:black; list-style-type:circle; margin:5px 0;}
```

Instead of a floating menu on the right side, IE8 renders the menu as first paragraph on top of the page. Where is my fault?

**Update:**

The relevant HTML:

```
<div class="toc">
<ul>
<li><a href="#toc_1">DOCS</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_2">TODO</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#toc_2.1">Vorlagen</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_2.2">Taeglich</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_2.3">ADVARIS</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_2.4">CRM</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_2.5">QIS</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_2.6">SAP</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_2.7">Verschiedenes</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#toc_3">URLs</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#toc_3.1">Dev</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_3.2">NEWS</a></li>
<li><a href="#toc_3.3">Vim</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

[Firefox-Screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?7406d7da23.png)

[IE-Screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?d09d8e7928.png)

Comment: Can you post an example with a URL, without the containing element(s) it's hard to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based of Gaby's provision, when I switch IE to render in Quirk's mode, then I believe I see your problem. Check your `Doctype` and other things that would through you into Quirk's mode, that's probably what is causing the issue.

Comment: It was the missing Doctype. Thank you very much!